# Dictionary iteration with many loops

Tags: c#, performance, beginner, hash-map

I have a dictionary iteration that uses a for-each comparisment in order to find multiple equalities in a string (fileline).

```
    //
    //  reads fileLine
    //
    public void readLine(string fileline)
    {
        //// turn fileline into desired format
        fileline = fileline.ToLower();
        fileline = fileline.Trim(StaticData.secondLvlSeperation);

        lineElements = fileline.Split(firstLvlSeperation, StringSplitOptions.None);

        if (lineElements.Length > 2)
        {
            alert = createAlert(systemname, diagnoseClass);
            //  == matched sequences when iterating through dictionary on each line new == //
            WordReader.fileLine = fileline;
            WordReader.matched = new HashSet<string>();
            WordReader.iterationCounter = 0;
            WordReader.lineLength = lineElements.Length;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (string lineElement in lineElements)
        {
            string trimmed = lineElement.Trim(); 
            WordReader.dictionaryIteration(trimmed);
        }

        checkAndAddAlert(alert);
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

`dictionaryIteration` below works as followed:

- > There is a dictionary `StaticData.keywords<string, string>` coming from a file that is loaded at start of Form.
- > The dictionary key is a string that holds a keyword which functions as an alert which could (or could not) be found in a file.
- > The dictionary value is a string that holds a value which is given to the keyword: ('critical', 'error' or 'informatic')

`<k,v>` example could be:

*"mengbed1 connected"* - *'informatic'* (**full sequence match in fileline**)

or

*"failed,insert,msstraat4"* - *'error'*  (**wildcard, multiple instances required in fileline**)

[image: Keywords in table]

1. `Iterator` 'hits' same number as fileline.length
2. Possibly the match-sequence formed is equal to one of the keys, key-match is found. Key is bound to alert
3. IF NO matched are found, we are possibly dealing with a wildcard-key
4. Fileline must contain -ALL- desired matched words coming from wildcard key in order to connect wildcard key to alert
5. No match of either sides means unknown alert

.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Logdog.Processors.Readers
{
    class WordReader
    {
        public static HashSet<string> matched;
        public static string fileLine;
        public static int lineLength;
        public static int iterationCounter = 0;


        //
        //  searches for match sequences in dictionary 
        //
        public static void dictionaryIteration(string wordToCheck)
        {
            iterationCounter++;

            //// match-forming in order to maintain right match sequence after 'hitting' filelength
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in StaticData.keywords.Where(ek => !ek.Key.Contains(',')))
            {
                string keyword = entry.Key;

                string[] keywords = keyword.Split();

                foreach (string keywordpart in keyword.Split())
                {
                    if (keywordpart.Equals(wordToCheck))
                    {
                        matched.Add(keywordpart);
                    }

                }
            }

            //// at the end of the line
            if (iterationCounter.Equals(lineLength))
            {
                compareMatchedSeq();
            } 

            //// when no equality found at all
            if (Linereader.alert.alertType == null)
            {
                Linereader.alert.alertType = "Unknown";
                Linereader.alert.alertKeyword = "Undefined";
            }

        }

        //
        //  compares the match sequence with dictionary elements
        //
        private static void compareMatchedSeq()
        {
            string matchedSeqRegular = string.Join(" ", matched);

            // first check on direct match equality
            KeyValuePair<string, string> matchedEntry = StaticData.keywords.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Key.Equals(matchedSeqRegular));

            if (matchedEntry.Key != null)
            {
                Linereader.alert.alertKeyword = matchedEntry.Key;
                Linereader.alert.alertType = matchedEntry.Value;
            }
            // if none found, this would mean this sequence is a wildcard type of key 
            else
            {
                int matchCounter = 0;

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> wildCardEntry in StaticData.keywords.Where(ek => ek.Key.Contains(',')))
                {
                    string[] keywordParts = wildCardEntry.Key.Split(',');

                    // check if all required matches are qualified
                    for (int i = 0; i < keywordParts.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (fileLine.Contains(keywordParts[i]))
                        {
                            matchCounter++;
                        }
                    }

                    // when all matched 
                    if (matchCounter.Equals(keywordParts.Length))
                    {
                        Linereader.alert.alertKeyword = wildCardEntry.Key;
                        Linereader.alert.alertType = wildCardEntry.Value;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have the idea that I may make too many for-each loops, (inc. the LINQ usage as well) but when trying other ways around the methods no longer work as desired so this is why I am asking this community if I indeed do have too many loops.

Comment: How are `fileLine` and `StaticData.keywords` declared? Can you show some sample data? It is difficult to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Happens in other class, I can add this

Comment: The point is that the data structure used for those determine if you can use fast lookups or need slow loops. With the right collection types, you can eliminate loops. So, it is essential to know how they are declared.

Comment: The dictionary StaticData.keywords comes from a file at formload();

Comment: So, if understand right `fileLine` is declared as `string fileLine;`.  How is `StaticData.keywords` declared? As `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` as `Dictionary<K, V>`, as `HashSet<something>`, something else? It looks suspicious to me that iterating keywords yields `KeyValuePair<string, string>` and that you are looping with `Where`. This is not the way a dictionary should work. The `readLine` method it not what we need to know, just the declaration of the variable, i.e. `string fileLine` and `someUnknownType  keywords`.

Comment: I see that my <string, string> got removed when edit posted. The declaration of fileLine comes from the other method, so I included this method.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'slow loops' but as far as I know LINQ must loop just as much as a regular loop with a break at matchpoint.

Comment: Please post the complete class, not just parts of it. There's lot more wrong with it the this, e.g. everything being `static`.

Comment: Not exactly sure what is wrong with using static rather creating instance of the object, but the class is coming up, editing right now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151768/are-global-static-classes-and-methods-bad/

Comment: My gut tells me that you did not understand the link you've posted. It clearly says that global data is bad and that's exactly what you are doing. The four public fields are global data and this really bad.

Comment: Gonna change this, I used to avoid global data but I misunderstood a few things and went with global statics, which is not good

Comment: Regarding properties vs constructors: constructors and methods give you more control to enforce class invariants (= valid states). Regarding static/global data, it tends to be accessed a lot, creating many more (somewhat hidden) dependencies, and that makes code harder (or impossible) to maintain and reuse. Another problem is that you're doing a lot via 'side-effects'. 'Pure' functions are easier to test and reason about, because they always produce the same output for the same input - they don't depend on anything else. Try doing more with parameters and return values.

Comment: I used to do this, but when I sarted improving my way of coding I in fact went from what is to good what is now bad. which means starting removing public statics and re-consider how I can use these properties in multiple classes without going possible bad practise. At the moment I am still reading upon this and I am still not sure which route to take. The program works now as wished but as a student I want to prevent myself doing bad practises. Now I ironically brought myself into one

Comment: The closer I look at this code, the more confusing it gets, and the more apparent it is that your post is missing some important details (such as the `StaticData` fields and their content, specifically what you're splitting strings on). Some example inputs and expected outputs would be useful too, because the code doesn't seem to fully match your description, and there are a few subtle things that can cause different (broken?) results.

Comment: A few confusing cases (assuming that you're splitting on whitespace): `readLine("mengbed1 connected")` produces no alert at all (is that intentional?), `readLine("mengbed1 is connected")` produces an informational alert (I expected that behavior only for wildcard filters) and `readLine("connected mengbed1 thirdword")` produces an unknown alert (apparently the order of appearance does matter). The only difference between normal and wildcard filters seems to be the order in which words must appear, is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes, this is what is intended. This specific question may just turn out to be to big to ask, but the only relevant section is the looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the dictionary `StaticData.keywords` in a wrong way. I assume (since we still not have your declaration) that it is declared as

```
public static class StaticData
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> keywords = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

The dictionary is implemented as hash table. Hash tables have a near constant **lookup** time. I.e., it makes no difference whether it contains 20 entries or 20,000 entries. The lookup time is the same. The [Big O notation](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/) is often used to describe this behavior. For a constant lookup time, this is **`O(1)`**.

If, however, you **loop** through the dictionary, you have a linear access time, denoted as **`O(n)`**. I.e., It takes 1000 times more time to lookup 20,000 than 20 entries.

Therefore, try to eliminate dictionary iterations. This not easy, as you have multiple key parts per entry and probably the same key part can occur in several entries.

Therefore, you need a multi-dictionary that can contain several entries per key (I'll be using the key parts, i.e. the keywords, as separate keys in the dictionary). There is no such collection in the .NET library; however, you can easily create one by combining a `Dictionary<K,V>` with a `List<T>`

```
public class MultiDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>
{
    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (TryGetValue(key, out List<TValue> valueList)) {
            valueList.Add(value);
        } else {
            Add(key, new List<TValue> { value });
        }
    }
}
```

You also need a class that can store alert entries appropriately:

```
/// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the AlertEntry class.</summary>
/// <param name="keywordsString">The keywords string, e.g. "failed,insert,msstraat4".</param>
/// <param name="alertType">Type of the alert. e.g. "informatic".</param>
public class AlertEntry
{
    public AlertEntry(string keywordsString, string alertType)
    {
        Keywords = keywordsString.ToLower().Split(',');
        AlertType = alertType;
    }

    public string[] Keywords { get; } // This is storing the key parts of your key.
    public string AlertType { get; }
}
```

Now, change the type of the keywords dictionary to

```
public static class StaticData
{
    public static MultiDictionary<string, AlertEntry> AlertEntries { get; } =
        new MultiDictionary<string, AlertEntry>();
}
```

Add alert entries like this (it's the same for full match keys or wildcard keys):

```
var alertEntry = new AlertEntry("failed,insert,msstraat4", "error");
foreach (string key in alertEntry.Keywords) {
    StaticData.AlertEntries.Add(key, alertEntry);
}
```

And finally, find matching sequence like this

```
private static void CompareMatchedSeq()
{
    string matchedSeqRegular = String.Join(" ", matched);

    // Fast lookup, no iteration (not even hidden inside FirstOrDefault)!
    if (StaticData.AlertEntries.TryGetValue(matchedSeqRegular,
                                            out List<AlertEntry> matchedEntries)) {
        AlertEntry matchedEntry = matchedEntries[0]; // Assumes matched entries
                                                     // only contain one entry.
        Linereader.alert.alertKeyword = matchedEntry.Keywords[0];
        Linereader.alert.alertType = matchedEntry.AlertType;
    } else {
        // If none found, this would mean this sequence is a wildcard type key.
        string[] fileLineKeys = ExtractKeywordPartsFromFileLine(); // TODO: Implement it!
        // Lookup by first fileLine key (could take any other). Again no iteration!
        if (StaticData.AlertEntries.TryGetValue(fileLineKeys[0],
                                                out List<AlertEntry> entries)) {
            // Find best matching entry, i.e. the one with the most keys matching.
            foreach (var wildCardEntry in entries.OrderByDescending(e => e.Keywords.Length)) {
                if (wildCardEntry.Keywords.All(k => fileLineKeys.Contains(k))) {
                    // When all matched.
                    Linereader.alert.alertKeyword = String.Join(",", wildCardEntry.Keywords);
                    Linereader.alert.alertType = wildCardEntry.AlertType;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are other issues. I will not address all of them. One is the naming. There are [Naming Guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) for C# and other .NET languages. And remove this `GC.Collect();`! The garabge collector does the things right by itself.

Comment: Thank you for this answer and I really appreciate the effort. 

However I do not understand what you mean with "multiple keys per entry"   this is not the case. 

There is one entry containing one key, with only one value. No more is possible. I will add an image to my question

Comment: I mean in `"failed,insert,msstraat4" - 'error'` there are 3 keywords (`"failed"`, `"insert"` and `"msstraat4"`) belonging to one alert type (`"error"`), which together form one alert entry. In `Dictionary<K,V>` terms they are keys and "error" is the value.

Comment: In my implementation I am using the 3 key parts as 3 different keys in the dictionary. Therfore your key is converted into 3 dictionary keys to enable fast lookup and to avoid looping through the dictionary entries.

Comment: What other issues than naming? I know about the naming, I do this on purpose since I am the only one working on this, and it was a BlueJ thing in my college (where it started all)

Comment: Furtheron I will implement the code with less iterations, to get me further in best practise. Thank you very much for teaching me

Comment: To summarize, avoid looping (this also includes LINQ queries) through dictionaries. Change the structure to allow fast lookup (`TryGetValue` or indexer `dictionary[key]`). You will notice a significant speed up!

Comment: Thank you for the time you have taken for me. I will start working on my code to see any other possible efficiency increments.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes What is the reason for creating a `MultiDictionary` class with it's own `Add` method? Why not just use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` ?

Comment: Because an ordinary dictionary can only store one value per dictionary key. If you have entries like "failed,insert,msstraat4"-"Informatic" and "failed,delete,msstraat3"-"Critical" and I create a dictionary entry for each one of the keywords, the "failed" keyword will have two values.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes  It's more readable to just use a standard `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` in that case.  It's not a good idea to inherit from collection classes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12075190/2089286.

Comment: @BradM: but inserting a new entry becomes cumbersome and error prone then.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes You could just abstract that functionality into a new method.

Comment: Or use an extension method. I just find the MultiDictionary very handy.

Comment: In the end no dictionary was required after all, I the Keyword became an object to hold more values coming further of use in the program anyway.